# Condition on TrustPilot Reviews

Tags: magento2, third-party-module

I am using Magento 2 extension for TrustPilot to display reviews on the Product detail page. I want to restrict if that product has minimum no of reviews means, only Trustpilot content should display.

Is there any way to achieve it.?

Also, it may help if I get to know to no of reviews on those products. Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems possible only if you are able to call TristPilot Api's to fetch details if review is added or not.

I think on details page you need to call TrustPilot api to get that product review and apply your condition as needed.

May be these links be helpful in achieving the same:

https://developers.trustpilot.com/product-reviews-api
https://developers.trustpilot.com/tutorials/how-to-get-product-reviews-from-the-trustpilot-api

May be this one be helpful:
https://developers.trustpilot.com/product-reviews-api#get-product-reviews